# How to clear cache for a URL in URLCache.shared?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurlcache

Is it possible to clear the URL Cache for just one url and not the whole cache? I have already tried this put it does not seem to do anything.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLCache.shared.removeCachedResponse(for: request)
```

Comment: That does not make sense. If you don't want cache to be used, you should handle that using `request.cachePolicy`.

Comment: Note that cache item is not keyed only by url. It depends on other things, too, mainly the headers.

Comment: This actually works pretty good now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try make request to some url with different cache policy like **reloadRevalidatingCacheData** which will delete all cache for this url.

Comment: Careful with this specific policy on older OS versions though: "Versions earlier than macOS 10.15, iOS 13, watchOS 6, and tvOS 13 don’t implement this constant." Use e.g. `reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` in that case instead.